# How to recognize small words with keyword recognizer or anything on windows on Unity?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine

I'm using phraseRecognizer to detect small keywords and using recognition event. This recognizer will work for simple and big words but will not work with small words. For example:

```
private string[] st = { "Aaa", "Be","up", "C","Hello", "D");


private KeywordRecognizer m_Recognizer;

void Start()
{

        Debug.Log("starting keyRecognizer");
        m_Recognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(st);
        m_Recognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += OnPhraseRecognized;
        m_Recognizer.Start();
}
//rest of the code is similar to official documentation.
```

It doesn't recognize any other keyword except the keyword"Hello". How can I make my computer recognize the simple and small words?

Answer (score 0):

I do not have experience with the KeywordRecognizer of Unity, but have you tried to tweak `Windows.Speech.ConfidenceLevel`? You can pass it as a second parameter into the constructor of KeywordsRecognizer.

Also, you might try your luck with `DictationRecognizer` in the same namespace. At least you can use it to get an insight of what it recognizes when you're trying to say "Aaa" or "D".

Comment: I dont know how to use `Windows.Speech.ConfidenceLevel` with which on Unity. I tried DictationRecognizer that hardly recognizes small letters spoken and seems to be good for common words.

Comment: Then I'm afraid there's nothing much you can do, as both use the same recognizer under the hood.

Comment: Dictation recognizer with unity is something different than keyword recognizer, not same. :) 
I find Dictation recognizer is much better for anything to recognize.